# Something wrong with C wrapper for Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, dll, wrapper

I'm currently facing an apparently silly problem with Matlab but I just can't figure out what is wrong (or better yet, I think it is wrong, but I'm being told it should work).

I have a Matlab script, "myscript.m" which needs to use a C-programmed function, "myfunc.c" which in turn has been compiled (or "lives") inside a library, "mylib.dll". In order for "myscript.m" to access and execute "myfunc.c" there is also a "myfunc.m" Matlab script, which is being called in "myscript.m". However, "myfunc.m" is a completely empty file, except for some comments (in no particular format or pattern either). All of these files were given to me and I'm being told that as it is, Matlab should correctly execute "myfunc.c" because "myfunc.m" is acting as a wrapper.

The problem I'm having is that it is of course not working. When I execute the line in "myscript.m" that reads:

```
output1 = myfunc(input1, input2);
```

I get Matlab errors saying that I'm trying to execute a script as a function. In my mind, this is correct, because I'm sending input and requesting outputs to something that is stated to have neither, since "myfunc.m" is empty (except for the comments, which are NOT code).

I think that Matlab has no way (as it is) to know that I want to access the C code inside "mylib.dll". I also DO NOT have a header file "mylib.h" so that I can load the library in Matlab using loadlibrary.

My question is, given the current description, could this execution work at all? Is there any way to make it work, or something that I'm missing? One possibility is that this is an old wrapper format and it currently doesn't work anymore.

If anyone knows anything or has suggestions, they will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

Hugo

Comment: could you perhaps move myfunc.m out of the way (or even delete it)?

Comment: I've tried, however I get the following (expected?) error message: "Undefined function myfunc.m for input arguments of type 'double'.". According to my reasoning, this is ok, since Matlab still doesn't know it must somehow link to the .dll; therefore, it just sees a function call and when it looks for it, it finds it nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like myfunc.c is a mex file. try compiling it in Matlab using `mex` command. The `dll` extension is maybe old version matlab.

Comment: I think I explained something incorrectly. There is not an actual "myfunc.c", there is only a C-coded function by the name of "myfunc". Normally there should be (somewhere) a file with the actual name of "myfunc.c". However, I don't have it.Therefore, I can't compile it on my own and need to use some kind of access to the .dll.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have one `mylib.dll` file and one `myfunc.m` file that has no matlab commands - only comments. One possibility is that `mylib.dll` is an old version of `mex` file: try calling it as a function in matlab and see what happens: `>> res = mylib(input1, input2);`. Where did you get these files from? Have you downloaded them? Is it possible your firewall/antivirus removed some of the files you tried to download? Can you get source files?

Comment: I've tried, but it still does not recognize `mylib.dll` as anything (either script, function, or variable). Whether `mylib.dll` and `myfunc.m` share the same name or not also does not have any effect. I got these files from a work colleague, who claims to have it working. At least the set of files we both have are the same, but there might be some hidden compiled library somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: I think the main question needed to be answered if we want to solve this is: is your code an old mex function, **or** a call to loaded share library. In order to try and figure this one out, please download http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and look at the dependencies of the dll. Looking at the list of functions `depends` extracted from the `dll`: Do you see there a function called `mexFunction` **or** `myfunc` ????

Comment: I've tried the dependencywalker software. There is a mention to a `mexFunction` and it also complains that it cannot find a `LIBMEX.dll` and `LIBMX.dll`.

Comment: Okay! your dll is an old version mex function (I do not remember at which version they changed the extension from dll to mexw32). However, you need to make sure `libmex.dll` and `libmx.dll` are in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Make sure you got these `dll`s in `matlabroot\bin\win32`

Comment: What exactly happens when you type `>> res = mylib(input1, input2)` ?

Comment: Great! I'll try it and see how that goes. When I do `>> res = mylib(input1,input2` Matlab simply complains that: `Undefined function or variable 'mylib'`.

Comment: is `mylib.dll` in your matlab's path?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder where `myscript.m` is located, which is the one calling `mylib.dll`

Comment: Ok, new problem: I don't have Matlab actually installed in my PC, but it is running through some servers; a.k.a. I have no way of modifying the contents of the `matlabroot\bin\win32` directory. Is there any way to tell Matlab to look for that libraries in some other directories?

Comment: try this solution http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch_eng11.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [`loadlibrary`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html)? You need a .h file but it's easy recreate on if you know the prototype of the function.